# Dummy Project Structure for Java Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, project-structure

There are certain conventions for having a decent project structure while working with Java Spring Framework. Different packages, different properties file, beans.xml files and other packages and classes for a maintainable and readable project. Can anyone please provide me with the same. Also some dummy package names and class names would be really helpful for me to start with.
Thanks!

Comment: Try an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij Idea. They come with built in templates for creating spring projects.  Failing that have a look at the online tutorials, as they have good examples

Answer (score 1):

You should use Maven archetypes to create standard conventions of Project Structures in any framework. 
You can use STS (Spring Tool Suite) or Spring Initializer for creating Spring Project skeletons with different modules of Spring tied up (optional).
Moreover, Spring is a very well supported community. You'll find many well-documented open source projects on Git for reference.